Open source implementations of euclidean geometery automated theorem provers
I plan to work on extending a theorem prover which is specialised in generating proofs for questions based in euclidean geometry which is taught to high school students to introduce them to the ideas of proofs and reasoning.  Some open source implementations that I have found are JGEX (Java Geometery expert)and GeomericTheoremProver library in Julia. However I believe that these are very much based on algebraic methods,(i.e is encoding the premises and the statement as a polynomial). I am looking for an implementation that is based on synthentic methods1. I want to find an implementation that closely relates to GEOM2 or QED_TUTRIX3
1)https://www.mat.uc.pt/~pedro/cientificos/presentationUrbino2019.pdf

Coelho, Helder; Pereira, Luis Moniz, Automated reasoning in geometry theorem proving with Prolog, J. Autom. Reasoning 2, 329-390 (1986). ZBL0642.68161.

Font, L., Cyr, S., Richard, P.R. and Gagnon, M., 2020. Automating the generation of high school geometry proofs using prolog in an educational context. arXiv preprint arXiv:2002.12551.



Perhaps take a look at Google's AlphaGeometry: https://github.com/google-deepmind/alphageometry (most of the code is for finding proofs, but they have their own self-contained implementation of a proof language, see alphageometry.py and graph.py). Unfortunately it's not maintained or well documented. They also cite https://github.com/rkruegs123/geo-model-builder - turns out making a good-looking diagram from just terms is surprisingly difficult.
